# The Actions tab shows workflows created in main branche's /.github/workflows/ only

Tags: github-actions

The Actions tab shows workflows created in main branche's /.github/workflows/ only

[image]

I have workflow.yml files with `workflow_dispatch` trigger that are defined in another branch (test) that are not yet merged into the main branch

Is there any way I can see and run workflows with `workflow_dispatch` trigger that are created in another branch not yet merged with the main branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you can't change at the moment. It takes actions from default branch. You can change default branch but I assume that this is not acceptable for you (which I understand). Please take a look [here on github community -
Workflow files only picked up from master?](https://github.community/t/workflow-files-only-picked-up-from-master/16129/16)

Comment: @AllanXu can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a web browser, you will see a dropdown - `Use workflow from`

If you use GitHub CLI, you need to use `--ref` flag

> gh.exe workflow run workflown_name --ref branch_name -f param_name=value

documentation is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow)

Comment: When you just created a wf.yaml file exists in branch other than main, you won't find it to see the dropdown. You must create an empty one in main so you can see it and choose the dropdown. Could be very confusing if you don't know how it works. Please upvote the question.